# How do I put items into a vector which has a type of a templated super class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, visual-c++

Assume I have the following 2 classes `Super` and `Deriv` where `Deriv` is a subclass of `Super`.

`Super` and `Deriv` are both templated classes. I want to create a `vector` of type `Super<?>`. Where the `?` signifies any type. Currently I have come up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class Super {
public:
    T val;
    Super(T val) : val(val) {};
};

template <typename T>
class Deriv : public Super<T> {
public:
    Deriv(T val) : Super<T>(val) {};
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Super*> a;
    a.push_back(new Deriv<int>(1));
    a.push_back(new Deriv<float>(1.0f));

    std::cout << a[0]->val << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course this does not work because `std::vector<Super*>` needs a template type like `std::vector<Super<int>*>`. However the problem with this is I can only add items to the vector of type `Super<int>*` and not `Super<float>*`.

How can I alter this code to allow me to add a `Super` type or it's derivatives to a vector which has any template type like `int`, `float`, `short` etc?

Comment: Have `Super` derive from `Base` which is not a template class, and then you can create a `std::vector<Base*>` Don't forget to add virtual destructor to `Base`.

Comment: I'm guessing `std::vector<Super<T> *>` is unacceptably restrictive, yes?

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried that, but where would my `T val` variable go? If i put it in `Base` I would have to push the template type up the hierarchy and would be back to where I started. Else I would need to do a cast when accessing the vector elements to get `T val` out?

Comment: `T val` stays in `Super` Have a read of __Covariant return types__ http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual

Comment: C++ is a statically typed language. The type of the expression `a[0]->val` must be known at compile time. You however seem to expect it to magically morph at run-time depending on the code that executed earlier. C++ doesn't work like this - ain't no way you can pull that off.

Comment: @RichardCritten but how do I get `val` when accessing an element? I would have to cast, but cast to what? `Super<float>*`?  `Super<int>*`? How would I know? Perhaps you should write an answer I'll probably accept if all i have to do is create an empty interface

Comment: `Super<int>` and `Super<float>` are unrelated types.

Comment: It would be usefull to know what is the **real** purpose of your code. I don't think it's just about printing the value, right?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this can solve your problem, but it might give you some ideas. The basic idea here is to make a super class for all kinds of `T`. For fundamental data types, wrapper classes are needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class SuperT {
public:
    virtual std::string AccessData() = 0;
};

class IntWraper : public SuperT {
public:
    IntWraper(int i) : val(i) { };
    virtual std::string AccessData() { return std::to_string(val); };
private:
    int val;
};

class FloatWraper : public SuperT {
public:
    FloatWraper(float f) : val(f) { };
    virtual std::string AccessData() { return std::to_string(val); };
private:
    float val;
};


class RealSuper {
public:
    virtual std::string DoSomething() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
class Super : public RealSuper {
public:
    T* wraper_val_;
    Super(T* w_val) : wraper_val_(w_val) { };
    ~Super() { if(wraper_val_) delete wraper_val_; };
    virtual std::string DoSomething() { return wraper_val_->AccessData(); }
};

template <typename T>
class Deriv : public Super<T> {
public:
    Deriv(T* w_val) : Super<T>(w_val) {};
};

int main() {
    std::vector<RealSuper*> a;
    a.push_back(new Deriv<IntWraper>(new IntWraper(1)));
    a.push_back(new Deriv<FloatWraper>(new FloatWraper(1.0f)));

    std::cout << a[0]->DoSomething() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a[1]->DoSomething() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This

```
std::vector<Super*> a;
```

Is wrong.

There is no type named `Super` in your code. Yes, you declared something named "Super", but it's not a class, it's a class template.

The name of the feature says it all. It's a template. The compiler will use `Super` to generate new types at compile time.

For example, `Super<int>` Refer to the class generated by the compiler when filling the hole `T` in the `Super` template.

So why `a[0]->val` cannot possibly work? Well, imagine this:

```
template<>
struct Super<std::string> {
    std::string my_val;
};
```

We specialize `Super` so when instantiated with `std::string`, it no longer have the `val` member, but the `my_val` member.

Now, what do you expect this code to do?

```
std::vector<Super*> a;
a.push_back(new Deriv<std::string>);

std::cout << a[0]->val << std::endl;
```

Quite puzzling isn't it? You'd need a compilation error at runtime. Since the existence (or non existence) of variable is determined at compile time, it's not possible.

---

Now how can we solve your problem?

In your case, it would be as simple as adding an interface above `Super`, and exposing functions that implements behaviors needed to do your calculations:

```
struct Interface {
    void print(std::ostream) const = 0;
    bool lessThan(double) const = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Super : Interface {
    T val;

    Super(T val_) : val{val_} {};

    // We implement the needed behavior.
    void print(std::ostream o) const override {
        o << val << std::endl;
    }

    // Example of calculation
    bool lessThan(double rhs) const override {
        return val < rhs;
    }
};
```

Now you can do:

```
std::vector<Interface*> a;

// ...

a[0]->print(std::cout);
a[0]->lessThan(3.7);
```

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to get the value of `val`? `T GetVal()` We have a problem right? We can't drag the template type back into the interface or we're back at square 1.

Comment: If you want to do that, you must drag a generic list (of unknown type) to known type. Dynamic cast must be used in that case and they usually are a sign of bad design. However, `std::variant` seems to be the solution for you. If all used type are known in advance, you can extract the type of the variable back.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class `RealSuper` that cache the type is a possible workaround.

It is not perfect, but I am afraid that it can't be much better than this :-

```
class RealSuper{                                //<-- new class
    public: enum TYPE{ type_int, type_float, type_notIni };  // (yes, it is awkward)
    TYPE typee = type_notIni;
};
template <typename T>   class Super : public RealSuper { //<-- modify
    public:  T val;
    Super(T val) : val(val) {
        if( std::is_same<T, int>::value ){
            typee = type_int;
        }else if( std::is_same<T, float>::value ){
            typee = type_float;
        }
    };
};
template <typename T>  class Deriv : public Super<T> {
    public: Deriv(T val) : Super<T>(val) {};
};
int main() {
    std::vector<RealSuper*> a;
    a.push_back(new Deriv<int>(1));
    a.push_back(new Deriv<float>(1.0f));
    for(auto ele: a){
        switch( ele->typee ){
            case RealSuper::TYPE::type_int: {
                int value=static_cast<Super<int>*>(ele)->val;
                std::cout << value << std::endl; 
            };break;
            case RealSuper::TYPE::type_float :{
                float value=static_cast<Super<float>*>(ele)->val;
                std::cout << value << std::endl; 
            };break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### [live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19bf7bd4c65f898c)

Here is another [demo](http://ideone.com/mSdipc) to show an approach using the virtual function.

Comment: This would work, but I really do not want to get the value back as a string. It must be as the original type as I want to do calculations with it.

Comment: To check type, if you don't mind, you can `std::is_same<T, int or float>::value` and cache the `type` manually e.g. use some enum as non-static field inside `RealSuper` .... you have to `static_cast<int or float>`  manually again by using the `type` though.    .... Let me know if you want a concrete example.  It is quite awkward, but it is the way I did in some (rare) real world case.

Comment: @Donald Nut I have edited the answer to (not-so-elegantly) solve the issue.

Comment: @DonaldNut It somewhat sounds like `boost::variant` might help you out, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @aschepler  Thank.  I have never heard of it.  It looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have the feature you are asking for (I believe it is a kind of reification).  This means you cannot store arbitrary types in location one, then specify arbitrary operations in a completely unrelated source file in location two, then apply the operations to the data in location three.

There are many problems you can solve that are close to what you are asking for: Restrict what operations you want to do at location two, *or* restrict what types you store at location one, and the problem can be solved.  Alternatively, restrict what type x operation pairs you support at location three.

Note that composition of the restricted set of operations can also work.

In theory you can embed a full compiler or interpreter in a C++ binary, compile code and dynamically load it.  (This is basically how C#/Java manage reification).  This is rather impractical for most problems.  The language provides no support for this, but this is C++, you can do anything (write a Java/C# compiler even).

With no information about the underlying problem you need to solve, I cannot tell you which of the above is the correct approach.

This is the reason why "if I had X I coukd solve Y, but I cannot figure out X.  I know, I'll just ask stack overflow how to do X!" is known as an X/Y problem.  We can probably solve Y, but you asked about X which woukd solve Y without even describing Y.  Feel free to post the Y problem and ask about it.  Use the [ask a question] button above.

---

Restrict what types you handle at storage:

Store a `std::variant`.  Use `std::visit`.  Or write your own or use `boost::variant`.

---

Restrict what operations to perform:

Use type erasure to generate the per-type operation when you store the type.

---

Restrict the operation-type pairs at point of call:

Use RTTI to exctract what type is stored, have a large switch switch that then uses solution one.

Comment: <i>"or restrict what types you store at location one"</i>. I could live with this. Could you elaborate on how you could do this cleanly?

Comment: @donald `std::variant` or `boost::variant` or write your own.